# Booting up renders error: "ata1.00: revalidation failed (errno=-5)" in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

Sometimes, non-deterministically, when I boot I get this error:

```
[   xx.xxxxxx] ata1.00: revalidation failed (errno=-5)
[   xx.xxxxxx] ata2.00: revalidation failed (errno=-5)
```

Where the `x` characters are some numbers.

There's a thread, *[ATA Revalidation Failed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/206635)* . But of course it's just a bunch of "me too!" posts, since it's not Stack Overflow.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Edit your `/boot/grub/menu.lst` file as root and go to the following section:

```
## ## Start Default Options ##
## default kernel options
## default kernel options for automagic boot options
## If you want special options for specific kernels use kopt_x_y_z
## where x.y.z is kernel version. Minor versions can be omitted.
## e.g. kopt=root=/dev/hda1 ro
##      kopt_2_6_8=root=/dev/hdc1 ro
##      kopt_2_6_8_2_686=root=/dev/hdc2 ro
# (some_options_already_here)
```

Beside the part that only has the single hash mark `'#'`, add these options to the end of the line:

```
irqpoll all_generic_ide
```

So the section looks like this:

```
## ## Start Default Options ##
## default kernel options
## default kernel options for automagic boot options
## If you want special options for specific kernels use kopt_x_y_z
## where x.y.z is kernel version. Minor versions can be omitted.
## e.g. kopt=root=/dev/hda1 ro
##      kopt_2_6_8=root=/dev/hdc1 ro
##      kopt_2_6_8_2_686=root=/dev/hdc2 ro
# (some_options_already_here) irqpoll all_generic_ide
```

Do ***not*** edit the `kernel` lines that are in the rest of the file, because when Ubuntu automagically updates the kernel list, it will pull the options from the previously mentioned section, and overwrite all `kernel` lines.

Comment: Nevermind, this doesn't actually work.